# How to save output from mathematica file into some other format and then using it later?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, datastore, data-storage, mathematica-8

I have a large program in mathematica, and generate many outputs. However, I don't want those outputs to be visible in my program and I want to save the outputs in text or any other format.
Moreover I also want to call any of the outputs and perform some specific operations on it (plotting, squaring etc.) 
Please guide me in this respect.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Temporarily redirect the output of `Print` to a second file](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29238/280)." This solution also redirects standard output to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Export` function. If you want the output suppressed, use semicolons. See the help file on `Export` for more.

(I don't know what else to say..)

Answer (score 0):

Export function is the way to go.

For example, if you ever needed 1 billion digits of Pi:

> Export["pi-to-1B.txt", N[[Pi], 1000000000]];